# Characters generated by Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml cannnot be parsed using StAX

Tags: java, html, utf-8, stax, apache-commons-lang

I am trying to parse content of HTML table and write it to CSV.
I am trying StaX parser
The html contains escaped characters like `&nbps'` and `&amp;`

I am using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` to usescape the html line by line and write to a new file.

StAX still fails to parse the unescaped characters.

Please help me fix or handle this exception.

I test with below xml fragment - 
`<root><element>A &nbsp; B &nbsp; </element></root>`

I call below code to unescape html -

```
   StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(escapedHtml)
```

and write it to a file.

I then try to parse that file using Stax Parser -

```
public void unescapeHtmlFile(String filePath) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedWriter fileWriter = null;
    try{
    fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./out/UnescapedHtml.html"));

    String line = null;
    String unescapedLine = null;
    while((line=fileReader.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println("Before: " + line);
        unescapedLine = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(line);
        System.out.println("After: " + unescapedLine);
        fileWriter.newLine();
        fileWriter.write(unescapedLine);
    }
    }finally{
        fileReader.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

And the output is below-

```
Document started 
<?xml version="null" encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
Element started
<root>
Element started
<element0>
Characters
0123456   7890   ABC   DEF
Element ended
</element0>
Element started
<element1>
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,66]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:83)
    at parser.StreamParserTest.main(StreamParserTest.java:30)
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,66]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:83)
    at parser.StreamParserTest.main(StreamParserTest.java:30)
```

It fails to parse the unescaped value of `&nbsp;` 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes FileReader and FileWriter are old utility classes, that unfortunately use the current platform encoding. On Windows almost certainly not UTF-8. And XML in general is in UTF-8 (which indeed can represent *all* characters.

```
fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./out/UnescapedHtml.html"));
```

should be

```
fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("./out/UnescapedHtml.html"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

To be entirely honest, one should read `<?xml ...?>` and look whether it has an `encoding` attribute for the charset, default is UTF-8. That could be done with `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`, as UTF-8 stumbles over wrong multi-byte sequences.

Using StandardCharsets instead of Strings "UTF-8" does away with

1. an UnsupportedEncodingException to handle,
2. a magic constant.

The StandardCharsets are guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: Thanks Joop. My next problem is to handle characters like '&' in the xml in StAX. Since html has no CDATA, it is getting difficult to parse the document using StAX.

Comment: If further the HTML may be faulty, you might think of an other solution, like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).