# I am working for Marathi language in my NLP based project

Tags: java

I am using Marathi Wordnet.In this wordnet there are text documents including marathi words

I want to read these marathi documents in my java code.I have tried with using the BufferedReader and FileReader.But I failed.
This is the code I have tried.

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader("onto_txt");

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
String line=br.readLine();
while(line!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
    line=br.readLine();

}
fr.close();
br.close();
```

Comment: Please read about internationalization and locale here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/TOC.html

Comment: @kalyani mamulkar what is the error you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552315/characters-generated-by-apache-commons-stringescapeutils-unescapehtml-cannnot-be

Answer (score 0):

FileReader is an old utility class using the default encoding of the platform.

Assuming that the file is in UTF-8, better explicitly specify the encoding.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("C:/xyz/onto_txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

        line = br.readLine();
    }
} // Closes br
```

Using System.out again converts the line to the encoding of the platform. That might not be able to display the String `line`; hence the dump of every single byte. Not very informative, but it might clarify that where `?` is diplayed in the prior line, there really are Unicode characters.

Internally java String holds Unicode, and can contain any text. So you might process `line` as desired in the while.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I still cannot read the marathi words from that document.